# Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException: Can't write image data to path

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to save my decoded base64 into storage folder but I got this error message; even the permission storage and all subdirectories is `775`.

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException: Can't write image data to path
```

My code

```
$image = $request->image; 
            $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
            $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
            $imageName = str_random(32).'.'.'png';
          \Image::make(base64_decode($image))>save('avatar/'.$imageName);
```

Storage path: `/storage/app/public/avatar`

Comment: do you have created that path or not ?

Comment: @Thamer yes, the path exists.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you missed dash symbol before save method, it should be:

```
\Image::make(base64_decode($image))->save('avatar/'.$imageName);
```

Also, you can check if directory exists, if there is no such directory then create it:

```
if (!File::isDirectory($path)) {
    File::makeDirectory($path, 0775, true);
}
```

Don't forget to include File facade at the top:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
```